# getting an error - Caught error in Fine Uploader jQuery event handler: Object [object Object] has no method 'getUploads'

Tags: javascript, jquery, fine-uploader

UPpated this question.

the issue I am having is trying to get the number of jobs submitted using the getUploads API.

when I call the function I am always getting 0 (zero).

Not sure what I did incorrect.
Matt

```
<script>
// Wait until the DOM is 'ready'
$(document).ready(function () {
   var myUploader =  $("#fine-uploader").fineUploader({
     session: {
              endpoint: 'imageStatus.cfm',
              params : {transaction_id : <cfoutput>#client.transaction_id#</cfoutput>}
        },
        debug: true,
        request: {
            endpoint: 'upload.cfm',
            params : {details : "<cfoutput>#client.wallfolder#|#client.DonatorID#|#client.wallid#|#client.transaction_id#|#client.clientid#</cfoutput>"}
        },
     validation: {
            itemLimit: <cfoutput>#evaluate(client.numberofbricks*3)#</cfoutput>,
            allowedExtensions: ["jpeg", "jpg", "gif" , "png"],
            sizeLimit: 5000000 // 5 MiB
            },
    messages: {
        tooManyItemsError: 'You can only add <cfoutput>#client.numberofbricks#</cfoutput> images'
            },
    deleteFile: {
            enabled: true, // defaults to false
            endpoint: 'upload_delete.cfm',
            method: 'post',
            params : {wallid : "<cfoutput>#client.wallid#</cfoutput>"}
            },
    retry: {
           enableAuto: false
            },
    scaling: {
            sendOriginal: true,
            hideScaled: true,
            sizes: [
                {name: "THUMB_XX", maxSize: 113},
                {name: "FULLIMAGE", maxSize: 450}
                ]
            }
    })
.on('allComplete', function(responseJSON) {
        if (qq.status.UPLOAD_SUCCESSFUL == 'upload successful') {
        //get uuid for message  
             if ($(this).fineUploader("getNetUploads") > 0){
              $("#ContinueButton").show();
                }else{
              $("#ContinueButton").hide();
            };
    }
})//on
.on('sessionRequestComplete', function(event, id, fileName, responseJSON) {
       if ($(this).fineUploader("getNetUploads") > 0){
              $("#ContinueButton").show();
       };
 })//on
.on('deleteComplete', function(event, id, fileName, responseJSON) {
       if ($(this).fineUploader("getNetUploads") == 0){
              $("#ContinueButton").hide();
       };

    var submittedFileCount = myUploader.fineUploader("getUploads", {status: qq.status.SUBMITTED});
    alert(submittedFileCount); 

});//on

$('#ContinueButton').click(function() {
var submittedFileCount = $('#myUploader').fineUploader('getUploads').length
alert(submittedFileCount);
});

}); //close of top script - required
```

Comment: `(qq.status.UPLOAD_SUCCESSFUL == 'upload successful')` will **always** be true. No need to check for that in `onAllComplete`

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing `myUploader` is the value returned by `$("#uploader-container").fineUploader({...});`, which is a jQuery object.  In that case, you are trying to invoke `getUploads` on a jQuery object, which of course will not work.

If you want to make this call on the plug-in when using the jQuery wrapper, you'll need to do so like so:

`myUploader.fineUploader("getUploads", {status: qq.status.SUBMITTED});`

Comment: Ok that initial but still trying to get the  of array.lengthmyUploader.fineUploader("getUploads", {status: qq.status.SUBMITTED}).lenght is not returning anything.
thoughts?  Thanks again

Comment: Please edit your question to show all of your current client-side code.

Comment: The call to `getUploads` in this case will return an array.  What specific issue are you having?  You mentioned that the call does not return anything.  What do you mean by that?

Comment: when I call this myUploader.fineUploader("getUploads", {status: qq.status.SUBMITTED}).length; I always get a 0 returned.

Comment: Your upload instance is tied to the element with the fine-uploader ID, not the myUploader ID, according to your code above.

Comment: ok maybe I can see the how to do this, but with the code above how can I use the getUloads API.  what would i need to change this line to work 
myUploader.fine-uploader("getUploads", {status: qq.status.SUBMITTED}).length;

Comment: That line should work just fine.  If the value is an empty array, that simply means that there are no files at that time with a current status of SUBMITTED.

Comment: Can you use the getUploads api in on('deleteComplete') event?
Testing only shows me a NULL array

Comment: Yes, you can use it anywhere.  If you are receiving a return value of null, there is likely an error in your call.  You are calling this API method several different ways (some of them incorrectly) in your code.

Comment: I figured it out.  the issue was the filtering of the call.
I had it as SUBMITTED and it should have been qq.status.UPLOAD_SUCCESSFUL

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of using `getNetUploads` within the `onAllComplete` handler with the jQuery uploader:

```js
.on("allComplete", function(responseJSON) {
    console.log("allComplete");
    if ($(this).fineUploader("getNetUploads") > 0) {
        console.log("#ContinueButton.show()");
        //$("#ContinueButton").show();
    }
    else {
        console.log("#ContinueButton.hide()");
        //$("#ContinueButton").hide();
    };
    var submittedFileCount = $(this).fineUploader(
        "getUploads", {
            status: qq.status.SUBMITTED
        });
    alert(submittedFileCount);
})
```

The same syntax should apply to any callback handlers your code.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. the issue was the filtering of the call. I had it as SUBMITTED and it should have been qq.status.UPLOAD_SUCCESSFUL